# How to find out homestead.com nameservers?

Tags: hosting, dns, nameservers

I have an old site created in homestead.com I redirected the domain to a new site last week but now want it redirected back. However I dont know what the nameservers are. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

```
 DNS server handling your query: localhost
 DNS server's address:  127.0.0.1#53

 Non-authoritative answer:
 Name:  homestead.com
 Address: 209.157.71.50
 homestead.com  nameserver = eeney.homestead.com.
 homestead.com  nameserver = miney.homestead.com.
 homestead.com  nameserver = meeney.homestead.com.

 Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Found out by using the online nslookup on [kloth.net](http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php)

Answer (score 0):

In Unix terminal `dig example.com` shows you the DNS entries for the domain. May or may not be of any use to you.